# display div with jQuery hasClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm struggling to get jQuery to detect if a section has a class or not. It doesn't show the div #onlyblogslide:

```
if ($("#section-8").hasClass(".blog-section")) {
        $('.onlyblogslide').show();
        $('.phone-link').css({'margin-right': '5px'});
    } else {
        $('.onlyblogslide').hide();
        $('.phone-link').css({'margin-right': '20px'});
    }
```

HTML for #section-8:

```
<div id="section-8" class="section  blog-section">content here</div>
```

Comment: the div #onlyblogslide doesn't show. It doesn't detect .blog-section I think even though its definitely on the div

Comment: [hasClass](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) takes just the name of the class not the selector, eg `blog-section` not `.blog-section`

Comment: if you’re looking for `#onlyblogslide` then do `$('#onlyblogslide)` not `$('.onlyblogslide')`

Comment: if ($("#section-8").hasClass(".blog-section"))  remove "." from blog-section.   Instead use this code if ($("#section-8").hasClass("blog-section"))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not include the period sign when using "hasClass".

The correct code should be:

```
if ($("#section-8").hasClass("blog-section")) {
    $('.onlyblogslide').show();
    $('.phone-link').css({'margin-right': '5px'});
} else {
    $('.onlyblogslide').hide();
    $('.phone-link').css({'margin-right': '20px'});
}
```